# Why traceroute of AWS public IP goes to the US?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ip, elastic-ip

I've used the traceroute command to see which network path packets are taking when reaching out to an EC2 instance with a public IP address.

I don't understand why at step 8 of the traceroute, packets are going to the USA (Seattle)

My EC2 is located in the AWS Paris region (eu-west-3) and my laptop making the request is located in Paris too.

Any idea why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP addresses are not actually associated with geographic locations. However, various services over time have *attempted* to map each IP address with a location.

See: [How does IP geolocation service providers collect data or how does IP geolocation databases are filled? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-IP-geolocation-service-providers-collect-data-or-how-does-IP-geolocation-databases-are-filled)

These activities are not always accurate and nobody is responsible for updating the information whenever devices are moved or addresses are reallocated.

Comment: Thank you John, it completely answers my question.

Indeed the software I used (Open Visual Trace Route) was wrong
(even after updating the geoip database).
geotraceroute.com gave me a result that is making more sense.

Thank you for the link too